# Does SVNKit support Subversion 1.9

Tags: svn, svnkit

We want to use SVNKit with latest Subversion. SVNKit site says that it is compatible with Subversion 1.8 and 1.7.

Does SVNKit support Subversion 1.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully used SVNKit 1.8.2 to access Subversion 1.9 working copies.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. SVNKit official page does not say about Subversion 1.9 support. May be in future SVNKit version they officially declare the support for Subversion 1.9

Comment: @andreas SVN 1.9 and SVN 1.8 use the same working copy format so that's expected. http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#wc-upgrade There will be problems when you try to access repos with SVN 1.9 format. However, I would generally discourage to use SVNKit to access the repositories directly via file:///